# node.js express-session dependency on cookieParser

Tags: node.js, express

BAsed on the docs i've read so far, they recommend that i explicitly include cookieParser in my code in order for express-session to work.

however, it looks like my session code works even if i don't "require("cookie-parser".  Is this because the express-session module itself includes and uses cookie-parser ?

Comment: The `cookie-session` middleware utilizes the `cookie-parser` middleware underneath, so you need to add `cookie-parser` prior to adding `cookie-session`. So, I don't know why your code is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will work without explicit use of `cookie-parser` since express-session [1.5.0](https://github.com/expressjs/session/releases/tag/v1.5.0) (specifically since [737211b56](https://github.com/expressjs/session/commit/737211b5629cb8eda4672023b99c763a92b3623b)).

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for clarifying that as well as the helpful link to the related check-in.